# How to add a popup menu with a customLayout with pointer arrow and anchor it to a view

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to make a popup menu with an arrow.

I saw there are many tooltip libraries similar to [this](https://www.viralandroid.com/2016/03/making-popup-window-with-tooltips-arrow-in-android.html) which have a similar layout but support only text. 
There is [this](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) library but that is very old and has depricated code.
There are two other libraries but they have horizontal menus with jagged edges with no text.

I am trying to add a customview to the popup menu anchored to a view with an arrow pointing towards the view something like this.

https://ibb.co/ftjnjCd

Alternatively I inflated a layout with a background with an arrow and added constraints progmatically but that is not what I am going for.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917610/7666442

Comment: I have been through that post. None of the libraries can help me make something like the screenshot I posted. They are years old with deprecated code and no material components. The cusomtooltip also uses an imageview for the arrow.